# Need to fetch row data from Sheet using excel

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider the below example Sheetname is "Summary" and its contain the data

Clientname    Sreerag

I need an output as Sreerag

Below code i tried for the same

"import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("D:\Sreerag_cigna.xlsx", sheet_name = 'Summary')
df_name = df_name[df_name['Unnamed: 3'].str.contains('Sreerag')]"

Comment: `df_name = df[df['Unnamed: 3'].str.contains('Sreerag')]`? What is your problem in fact?

Comment: from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd
wb=load_workbook("D:\Sreerag_cigna.xlsx")
ws = wb['Summary']
all_rows = list(ws.rows)

# Pull information from specific cells.
for row in all_rows[1:4]:
    state = row[1].value
    print(f"{state}")              ---Now the seems to be working